# How to execute searchAndRank method in IBM Watson Retrieve And Rank API through Java wrapper

Tags: java, ibm-watson, retrieve-and-rank

I am trying to perform a retrieveAndRank query using Java wrapper. I follow the online javadocs for Retrieve and Rank API.
The example there for SearchAndRank is:

https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/retrieve-and-rank/api/v1/#query_ranker

```
RetrieveAndRank service = new RetrieveAndRank();
service.setUsernameAndPassword("{username}","{password}");
HttpSolrClient solrClient = new HttpSolrClient;
solrClient = getSolrClient(service.getSolrUrl("scfaaf8903_02c1_4297_84c6_76b79537d849"), "{username}","{password}");
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery("what is the basic mechanism of the transonic aileron buzz");
QueryResponse response = solrClient.query("example_collection", query);
Ranking ranking = service.rank("B2E325-rank-67", response);
System.out.println(ranking);
```

but RetrieveAndRank class has no such rank(String rankerId, QueryResponse response) method. Just one getting a file or an InputStream as arguments (browsing IBM’s source code I see it expects CSV content not a java QueryResponse there).

How should I pass QueryResponse to the rank method?

I am using solr-solrj-5.5.2.jar and java-sdk-3.2.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar libraries

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `/fcselect` query handler and send the `ranker_id` as a parameter.

The code below assumes you have a Solr collection with documents and you have trained a ranker, otherwise follow this [tutorial](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/retrieve-rank/get_start.shtml).

```
 RetrieveAndRank service = new RetrieveAndRank();
 service.setUsernameAndPassword(USERNAME, PASSWORD);

 // create the solr client
 String solrUrl = service.getSolrUrl(SOLR_CLUSTER_ID);
 HttpClient client = createHttpClient(solrUrl, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
 HttpSolrClient solrClient = new HttpSolrClient(solrUrl, client);

 // build the query
 SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery("*:*");
 query.setRequestHandler("/fcselect");
 query.set("ranker_id", RANKER_ID);

 // execute the query
 QueryResponse response = solrClient.query(SOLR_COLLECTION_NAME, query);
 System.out.println("Found " + response.getResults().size() + " documents!");
 System.out.println(response);
```

Make sure you update the service credentials for RetrieveAndRank(`USERNAME` and `PASSWORD`), `SOLR_CLUSTER_ID`, `SOLR_COLLECTION_NAME` and `RANKER_ID`.
The code for `createHttpClient()` can be found [here](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/blob/master/examples/retrieve-and-rank-solrj/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/developer_cloud/retrieve_and_rank/RetrieveAndRankSolrJExample.java#L112).